# How to *relocate* certain rows from one sheet to another when using drop down filter menus in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, filter, macros

I do have a problem which sounds quite simple, but which is very difficult to solve when you are not used to programming Excel macros.

On `Sheet1`, there is a list of several tasks (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`). There is a status assigned to every task which states whether a task is `Not started`, `In progress` or `Completed`.
[image: Sheet 1]

On Sheet2, there is a list of `Completed` tasks.

[image]

Now, I want to write a macro which does the following: Whenever I change the status of one of the tasks on `Sheet1` from `Not started` or `In progress` to `Completed` (e.g. for task `D`),

[image: Sheet 1 with drop down menu]

I want Excel to *relocate* that line from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` in the following manner:

1. I want Excel to *remove* line `5` from `Sheet1`.
2. Then, Excel should move line `3` to line `4` and line `2` to line `3` in `Sheet2`
3. Now, Excel should copy the removed line (`5`) from `Sheet1` into the now empty line `2` of `Sheet2`.

I have looked around for various solutions, but all I found was just [some VBA-code that did not fit to my specific problem](http://www.supportnet.de/fresh/2006/4/id1327941.asp), no matter how hard I have tried to adapt it. It has been used to program a macro for a German version of Excel.

- `Zeile` = `Row`
- `erledigt` = `completed`
- `erledigte Projekte` = `completed projects`

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim Zeile As Long
  Set Target = Intersect(Target, Range("J1:J1000"))
  If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  If Target = "erledigt" Then
  Zeile = Target.Row
  Range(Cells(Zeile, 3), Cells(Zeile, 10)).Copy _
  Destination:=Sheets("erledigte Projekte").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
  Target.EntireRow.Delete
  End If
  End Sub
  ```

I can, sort of, understand that code, but I have never actually learned Visual Basic. Thus, I, unfortunately, do not know how to modify that code in order to make it work. I know that it is a (more or less) simple problem, but I do not know how to solve it. Therefore, I am asking for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all that if you name your task with a number (1,2,3,4...) instead of a letter (A,B,C...) it will be easier to fix this problem.

Doing this you could then compare the value of Cell(k,1), where k is the row which contains the new completed task, with the value of the other completed tasks in Sheet 2.

That's my 2 cents.